# What does exactly Identity functor do?

Tags: haskell

It may be trivial, but I don't understand what does the following mean.

```
instance Functor Identity where
    fmap     = coerce
```

So, I can try to define something similar:

```
Prelude Control.Lens Data.Functor.Identity> :t fmap
fmap :: Functor f => (a -> b) -> f a -> f b
Prelude Control.Lens Data.Functor.Identity> let z f g = coerce f g
Prelude Control.Lens Data.Functor.Identity> :t z
z :: Contravariant ((->) t) => (t -> a) -> t -> b
```

But, what does it mean in simpler terms?

Comment: What’s your version of GHC resp. base? I believe the use of `Data.Coerce.coerce` is a new one.

Comment: The identity functor is like the identity function &mdash; it does nothing. That sounds completely useless, but actually turns out not to be&hellip;

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The use of `coerce` is new in GHC 7.10 and is done for efficiency. The "real" definition is

```
fmap :: (a -> b) -> (Identity a -> Identity b)
fmap f (Identity a) = Identity (f a)
```

The wrapping/unwrapping of the `Identity` constructor should be optimized away at compile time, but it seems like the `base` devs had reason to ensure that there is no performance penalty by using `coerce`.

The reason we can use `coerce` is that `Identity a` is isomorphic to (the same as) `a`, so we can coerce `a -> b` to `Identity a -> Identity b` which happens to be the definition of `fmap` specialized to `Identity`!

Comment: Searching for zero cost coercions leads to a very nice talk by spj himself on this issue.

Answer (score 6):

Where did you find that functor instance for `Identity`? This is the one I find in `Data.Functor.Identity`:

```
newtype Identity a = Identity { runIdentity :: a }

instance Functor Identity where
  fmap f m = Identity (f (runIdentity m))
```

But as to what it does... it does absolutely nothing, and that's intentional. `fmap f (Idendity x)` is the same thing as `Idendity (f x)`. It just applies the function to the value it contains.

Why would you want to have a functor that doesn't do anything? If your function requires a functor, but you only have a regular non-functor value, you can wrap your value in `Identity` and pass it in and it will behave correctly. It's basically a layer of wrapping just to satisfy the typechecker.

Comment: Identity is also a monad